# SQL: Merge 2 Columns or more from different tables into one Alias new Column

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have 2 tables: DisconnectionsData and DisconnectionsVoice.
both of them have columns: WeekNum,Month,Quarter,Year,IncomeLost and ID.

**the names of the columns are different between the 2 tables, but the data inside them is parallel (Quarter and QuarterNumber is literally the same).**

my wish is to `FULL JOIN` both tables into one table with only 6 columns.
i cant figure out how to make an alias, for example: how do i merge DisconnectionsData.Quarter and DisconnectionsVoice.QuarterNumber
into one column with the alias name of QuarterOfDisconnection.

**that the desired result:**

[image]

thank you.

Comment: I'm confused.  Your first paragraph mentions two tables with the same columns.  Your third says that names are not the same.  Your example data has three tables, that each have two columns.

Comment: Do you want that a row from DisconnectionsData gets combined with a row from DisconnectionsVoice if possible?

Comment: sorry if i didnt explained myself clear. the data is parallel but the column names are different. - edited the question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't specify which sql are you using?  You can try below.

```
SELECT *
FROM DisconnectionsData
UNION ALL
SELECT * 
FROM DisconnectionsVoice
```

Comment: i am using MSSQL.

Comment: The `UNION` query takes the first `SELECT` as the column names, so if you put alias on the first query, you will get the NewName that you want.

Comment: `SELECT Quarter AS 'QuarterNewName', ID AS 'IDNewName'
FROM DisconnectionsData
UNION ALL
SELECT QuarterNumber, ID 
FROM DisconnectionsVoice`

Comment: theoretically the columns just have to be with the same datatype and the same order in each select and they will be union-ed ?

Comment: Yes, pretty much.